# Can't interact with javascript in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to setup my WebView to navigate into a site.
When I try to close the Cookie Policy (so, when I try to press on that button, I think there's a javascript), it doesn't do anything.
I've tried to use WebView.addJavascriptInterface, but without success.

Here's my code:

```
mWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
mNaviButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
mWebView.loadUrl("www.example.com");
}
});
```

How can I solve that?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Solved by adding "`mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`"

Comment: Edited, but it's a simple webview that loads an url.

Comment: webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Solved with Carnal's answer.